# Is there a way to set a cell to a certain value if it is set to a certain value in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I want to get all the data in one of my sheets and check for a specific value. Then I want to set the cell with that specific value to another value. I know I can use getDataRange() to get all the values, but how would I loop through and look for a specific value?

Comment: You need to bring us at least one minimally reproducible code, because the way you brought us, you can't even know the type of data you have in the worksheet, if it's multiple columns or just one, if it's numbers, strings, both. ..

It doesn't need to show personal data, but something visible, also including what you've already tried according to what you saw in the documentation.

Comment: Preferably share a spreadsheet with example values and put in a piece of code what you have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

#### Search and Replace

```
function searchAndReplace(n = 77) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const sr = 2;//data startrow
  const vs = sh.getRange(sr, 1, sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    r.forEach((c, j) => {
      if (c == n) {
        let r = ui.prompt("Enter new Value", ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL)
        if (r.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK) {
          sh.getRange(i + sr, j + 1).setValue(r.getResponseText());
        }
      }
    })
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method would be to use [TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder).

**Code:**

```
function findReplace() {
  const findValue = "foo";
  const replaceValue = "bar";

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const range = sheet.getDataRange();
  const textFinder = range.createTextFinder(findValue).matchEntireCell(true);
  textFinder.replaceAllWith(replaceValue);
}
```

All you'd need to do is change the `findValue` and `replaceValue` to the values you're looking for.

If you're looking for a code-less option, a [find and replace](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/62754?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop) (shift + Cmd + H) would also do the trick!